# Preventing delivery theft at condominium building

Tags: new-home

Over the last few weeks, numerous residents have had packages stolen from our unit. Last night, I went down to the entrance to find that my package had been ripped open. They left the box, but took the items inside which had a value of around $1,000. My roommate had a package stolen today.

The company which runs the homeowners' association responded with details of last nights' incident from security footage, and a generic response about improving the situation:

> A homeless person entered the property behind a vehicle, and stole packages & broke into the janitorial closet as stole supplies.
>
> Our team will investigating how to prevent people from breaking-in.

What can I do about this situation? I have previously lived in apartments with lockers for items delivered, though unsure about how I can get this installed to our building. I have read that HOA companies are notorious for being difficult to work with.

Comment: "You have read" on the internet "that HOA companies are notoriously difficult" because the pages that come up are people complaining about that.  That is not a reliable signal.  It is extremely biased, because people don't post on the Internet about happy relationships with HOAs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your right, HOA's can be impossible to deal with. They won't address this unless a majority of owners want to have it fixed. Installing lockers would be expensive and the delivery companies would have to have access to them. The USPS would probably tell you they'll deliver the packages but someone there would have to place them in the lockers. Your best bet right now is to have the packages delivered to a friend's address, or maybe to where you work. With so much shopping done online, this is becoming a major problem, even at private residences.